# How to simply perform a update/replace many documents operation in MongoDb

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, mongodb-.net-driver

This is perhaps one of the most common and basic database operations you can perform. However, how you perform this operation in MongoDb, is elusive.

There's a `UpdateManyAsync` method in the C# driver. But all I can find for it is examples like;

The following operation updates all documents where violations are greater than 4 and $set a flag for review:

```
try {
   db.restaurant.updateMany(
      { violations: { $gt: 4 } },
      { $set: { "Review" : true } }
   );
} catch (e) {
   print(e);
}
```

Frankly I don't know how you guys build your applications but our organization will never embed domain logic like how many violations constitutes a review in our database querying logic. Like all the examples I can find for this operation do.

It seems at best that our option is to use some sort of bulk api for this, which seems unnecessary for such a simple operation. Making the bulk api perform a thousand separate replaces seems ineffective to me, but I might be wrong here?

In other storage technologies and more mature API's all the code necessary to perform this operation is (example Entity framework);

```
db.UpdateRange(stocks);
await db.SaveChangesAsync();
```

Is this tracked as a feature request for the Mongo project somewhere?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Bulk API can handle it see code below:

```
            var updates = new List<WriteModel<CosmosDoc>>();
            foreach (var doc in docs)
            {
                updates.Add(new ReplaceOneModel<CosmosDoc>(doc.Id, doc));
            }
            await MongoDb.DocsCollection.BulkWriteAsync(updates, new BulkWriteOptions() { IsOrdered = false });
```

Comment: It is work fine :) thank you so much

Comment: would this solve the issue in cosmos with "too many requests"?
I have a use case where I have a large number of records that need to be updated at once. I was just looping before (which now seems crazy)  It was fine when we had mongo on prem.. but It throws these errors on cosmos db.

Comment: Now (2024), when I use this code, I am getting exception. So I have to use exact filter as first parameter of ReplaceOneModel. So now it looks like and works:
`updates.Add(new ReplaceOneModel<CosmosDoc>(Builders<CosmosDoc>.Filter.Where(d => d.Id == doc.Id), doc));`